# Categories, subcategories and items in a SharePoint site

Tags: list, categories

I need to make a SharePoint 2010 site with items which are attached to categories and subcategories (like a catalog).
What is the best approach?

- The first page will present a list of categories.
- The second page a list of the chosen category's subcategories.
- The third page will show the item attached to the category and subcategory.

Should I make 2 lists (category, subcategory), with a lookup field in the subcategory list. Then an item list, and use query strings (between the pages) and relational lists to access the items?

Is this an example of Master/Detail relationships?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having separate category and subcategory could you use a hierarchical term set?

You could then use that as a filter to show the items in a separate list view on the same page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I prefer not to use term sets.
Any other ideas for a catalog in SharePoint 2010 ? Thanks

Comment: The fact that you do not want to use term sets is quite strange, it is possible the ultimate way of arranging data, while still keeping a loose connection. E.g. you can move your terms in the hierarchy very easily

Comment: I must say that after looking into term sets, the concept is quite powerful.
I must now try to understand how to expose the terms on the website for users to narrow articles with a particular term.

Comment: Glad you are reconsidering.  Term sets are far from perfect but as Robert says, very powerful.  Not sure what sort of page you are using but if it is a publishing page then you can add a metadata column to the content type which points at the term set and then add that to the page layout.  Once there you can filter CQWPs using whatever term is added.